# mootools 1.4.0.1 - htmltable push

Tags: row, push, mootools, addition

in according with
http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.5.1/Interface/HtmlTable#HtmlTable
I have used push to add new rows, with some properties and positioning.

Here a snippet:

```
var table = new HtmlTable($('my_table_id')); 
var target  = "some code...";
table.push([
                td_val1,
                td_val2,
                td_val3,
                td_val4,
                { 
                    content: td_val5,
                    properties: {
                        'class': 'my_class'
                    }
                },
                td_val6,
            ], 
        (target !== undefined) ? {} : null, 
        (target !== undefined) ? target.parentNode : null, 
        (target !== undefined) ? 'td' : null, 
        (target !== undefined) ? 'after' : null
);
```

It work well with a empty table like (table.empty() before push):

```
<table id="my_table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
            <th>Col5</th>
            <th>Col6</th>
            <th>Col7</th>
            <th>Col8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="no_result">
            <td colspan="8">No results</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But no effect on a pre fill table like:

```
<table id="my_table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
            <th>Col5</th>
            <th>Col6</th>
            <th>Col7</th>
            <th>Col8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>val1</td>
            <td>val2</td>
            <td>val3</td>
            <td>val4</td>
            <td>val5</td>
            <td>val6</td>
            <td>val7</td>
            <td>val8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The push code is in a try/catch, but no excepetion raised.

I no focused the problem what is... Thanks so much for help.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle reproducing your error? It works to add on a table that is half filled... -> http://jsfiddle.net/1rk7sp72/

Comment: After some days... The push method work well, It was my fault on target calculation, thanks. solved